# Warning. Array(s) in Degraded Mode. What should I do?

Tags: raid

My Machine shows warning message on start up ?

Port 1 is in rebuilding state.

Warning. Array(s) in Degraded Mode.

Press any key to continue.....

Why it is showing warning ? Should I rebuild the RAID ?

or it requires fresh Installation of OS ?

Machine Configuration : Inter Pentium  3.0 HT processor, 3 GB RAM, Intel Entry Server  Board SE7230 NH1-E

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Laxmilal Menaria

Comment: You aren't providing enough specific information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point for the future: If you're going to run RAID it's a good idea to do a practice run of what actually happens when a disk outage occurs when you're setting the system up (before it accumulates too much precious data), so it's less of a surprise when it happens for real and you know how to recover.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of RAID device do you have? Is it a hardware or software RAID (and if so, what OS?)

As MarkM mentioned, there's an excellent chance that the degradation is caused by a failed drive. If you've got a hardware raid, you can probably see the bad drive because there will be a different colored LED.

If it's software RAID, then you know the port number (port 1, I guess?), but you can cat /proc/mdstat and learn more details about the status of the array.

Answer (score 2):

What RAID level? Usually this means a failed drive. If you can afford the risk, you can try a rebuild with that drive, but usually it will just fail again. You should replace whatever drive is in port 1 and rebuild.